# Accuracy of Edge length measurements

Tags: measurement

I've been trying to modell with some accuracy using Blender 2.8 using the **Edge Length** under `Viewport Overlays > Measurements`. However I've noticed that the measurement is not always accurate or at least when I use the [MeasureIt addon](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/measureit) the Edge length is different to the MeasureIt output.

This is with the same edge selected but two different measurements.

Edge Length: outputs 1.95cm

[image: Edge Length]

MeasureIt: outputs 1.0cm

[image: MeasureIt Addon]

Am I doing something wrong with Blender's edge length..?

Comment: Check if object scale is applied (Object mode > Ctrl+A  to apply)

Comment: Doh! Totally forgot.... That did it!

Comment: I forgot about '[Apply](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html?highlight=apply%20scale#apply)''ing my objects data after I started changing it in edit mode.